# Express-Handlebars is merging my array of arrays into a single string?

Tags: node.js, arrays, handlebars.js

Can you help please, this is most odd..

I have a custom class, that contains multiple properties, one of which is an array of arrays..

I know that the data structure is ok, because I can dump it to console.log, and app.send() results in a nicely formed array in my browser.

What's weird is that when I try to render it the data browser is correct, it's just not an array of arrays anymore, it's not an array at all, just a comma separated string...

So from

```
[[day,1,2,3],[day,1,2,3],[day,1,2,3]]
```

To

```
day,1,2,3,day,1,2,3,day,1,2,3
```

Even the outer array is gone.?

Any ideas?
Is there some setting I've missed?

Thanks in Advance,
Bob.

Update with some code..
app.js

```
    app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
    app.engine('hbs', hbs({
         extname: 'hbs',
         defaultLayout: 'layout',
         layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/',
         partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials/',
         helpers:{
              json: function (context){return JSON.stringify(context); }
              }
         }));
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

index.js

```
    class myClass{
       Name    = '';
       Stats   = [];
       constructor(name){
            this.Name = name;
            }
       }

    router.get('/', function(req,res,next){
       let tmp = new myClass('Dan');
       let i;
       for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
           tmp.Stats.push('day',1,2,3);
           }
       console.log(tmp.Stats);
       // res.send(tmp);
       res.render('index', { title: 'Test Data', data: tmp });
       });
```

The results are as described above, console.log and res.send both respect the array structure but render strips it to a string..?

Fortunately the array is a fixed size, so I can reconstruct it in a  block, but I'd rather know what I did wrong to cause the issue in the first place..

Thanks.

Comment: You need to add some code to show how/where you use it. It's impossible to help you without seeing any code.

Comment: It would  help to also see what your handlebars markup looks like from within your view.

Comment: Are you sure you have an Array of Arrays? `tmp.Stats.push('day', 1, 2, 3)` does _not_ push an Array to `tmp.Stats`, it pushes each item. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: Secondly, you should provide your Handlebars template so we can see what it is doing. I have to guess that you are _not_ using the `json` helper and are just asking Handlebars to print the Array with something like `{{ tmpStats }}`. If so, the `day,1,2,3,day,1,2,3,day,1,2,3` output you are getting is just the result of Handlebars stringifying the Array. You need to use the `json` helper in order to have JSON outputted.

Answer (score 0):

With above code you are *not* creating an array of arrays, in fact you are creating a **flat** array with 16 elements. If you want to push an array on each iteration you need to do:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    tmp.Stats.push(['day', 1, 2, 3]);
}
```

In your template you can then access the data and do something like:

```
<% for(let currStat of data.Stats) { %>
    <ul>
        <% for(let entry of currStat) { %>
            <li>
                <%= entry %>
            </li>
        <% } %>
    </ul>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Apologies, that's a typo, the code includes the [] which is why it show's correctly with send, My bad..

I've not seen this syntax <% %> with express-handlebars before..?
Any chance you have a link to the reference pages?

Comment: It was just an example with an ejs template, not hbs. Please edit your question and show how you use the array in your template.